# MySQL IN() Operator not working

Tags: mysql, sql

How to use IN() Operator not working it's.

Those table are example and look the same as the real database I have.**I don't have the permitting to add tables or change**

Those are the tables:

```
students
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | ali  |
|    2 | man  |
|    3 | sos  |
+------+------+

Classes
+------+---------+
| c_id | students|
+------+---------+
|    1 | 1,2,3,4 |
|    2 | 88,33,55|
|    3 | 45,23,72|
+------+---------+
```

When I use this query it return me only the student with id =1
because "**id IN (students)**" return 1 when the first value are equal.

```
select name,c_id from students,classes where id IN (students);
```

when I get the list out on PHP than add it. it work fine.But, this solution need a loop and cost many queries.

```
select name,c_id from students,classes where id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

> FIND_IN_SET()

the same happened, it's only return 1 but if the value on other position it return 0.

Comment: @Strawberry -_- how to make it Yessssssss?

Comment: See normalization. It's a tricky concept, but if I can get to grips with it, anyone can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IN` operator works just fine, where it's applicable for what it does.

First, consider restructuring your data to be normalized, and avoid storing values as comma separated lists.

Second, if you absolutely have to deal with columns containing comma separated lists of values, MySQL provides the **`FIND_IN_SET()`** function.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead. And relocate the join predicates from the WHERE clause to the ON clause. Fully qualify column references, eg.

```
SELECT s.name
     , c.c_id
  FROM students s
  JOIN classes c
    ON FIND_IN_SET(s.student_id,c.students)
 ORDER BY s.name, c.c_id
```

To reiterate, storing a "comma separated list" in a column is an **anti-pattern**; it flies against relational theory and normalization, and disregards the best practices around relational databases. O

One might argue for improved performance, but this pattern doesn't improve performance; rather it adds unnecessary complexity in query and DML operations.

Comment: I used FIND_IN_SET() and the same, when the id on the first it return 1. ex: FIND_IN_SET('1','1,2,3') but for 2 or 3 it's 0. JUST when I want to make it on one query.

Comment: `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('2','1,2,3')` returns `2`, not `0`. Some recommendations: ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead. Relocate the join predicates to an ON clause. And fully qualify all column references in a multitable query.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() with left join worked fine, there here a space after the comma on my database. after removing the spaces FIND_IN_SET() work perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need three tables.
One table `students`, one table `classes`, and then one table, say, `students_to_classes` containing something like

```
c_id | student_id
1    | 1
1    | 2
1    | 3
1    | 4
2    | 88
```

and so on.
Then you can query

```
select c_id from students_to_classes where student_id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Google "n:m relationship" for background on this.

EDIT

I know you're not specifically asking for another table structure, but this is a way of having a data type (a single number) that works with `IN`. Please believe me that this is the right way to do it, the reason you run into trouble with something as simple as `IN` is that you're using a non-standard approach, which, for such a standard problem, is typically not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, well put.  I'd just add that once he had the three tables, he originally asked for a query like:

SELECT name, c_id from students s inner join students_to_classes stc on s.student_id=stc.student_id;

(I think)

Comment: @ers81239 you are right, I'm not asking about a map table, the tables are just example. the main Q is that IN() return different result when I use it.

Comment: @alnassre I understand you're not asking for this, but it's the answer anyway ;) edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: OK saw the edit in your question... agree, not being able to change the DB, my answer isn't all that helpful :(

Comment: @Nicolas78 you answer helped me, I want to know other thing, why it's work fine when I take the list string on PHP and add it on other query but when it's the same query it's work with the first position only.

Comment: No idea, I'd suggest to open a new question with proper examples and everything...

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the function IN is supposed to work. You use IN when you have a list of possible matches like:

instead of:

```
WHERE id=1 or id=2 or id=3 or id=4
```

you use:

```
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Anyhow, your logic is not correct. The relation of Class and Student is Many-to-Many, thus a third table is needed. Let's call it `studend_class`, where you can store the students of each class.

```
student
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | ali  |
|    2 | man  |
|    3 | sos  |
+------+------+

class
+------+---------+
|  id  |  name   |
+------+---------+
|    1 | math    |
|    2 | english |
|    3 | science |
+------+---------+

student_class
+------------+-------------+
|  class_id  |  student_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |           1 |
|          1 |           2 |
|          1 |           3 |
|          3 |           3 |
+--------------+-----------+
```

In the example above all students are in math class and ali is also in science class.

Finally, if you whant to know which students are in what class, let's say Math, you can use:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, c.name
FROM student s
INNER JOIN student_class sc ON sc.student_id=s.id
INNER JOIN class c ON sc.class_id = c.id
WHERE c.name="math";
```